# ERROR plugin/errors: 2 accept.test01pvtokesn0.test01vcn.oraclevcn.com. A: read udp 10.244.1.246:44694->172.20.100.71:53: i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes, service, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, coredns, fqdn

I'm getting this error in my coredns pod. I believe because of this when I'm trying to access services with FQDN(service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local) there is a delay of ~15sec but all the services are accessible quickly with service-name only.

I'm not sure what's the issue.

Expecting to resolve services FQDN without delay.